# vagrant ssh-config is very slow

Tags: vagrant

The `vagrant ssh-config` command takes more than 12 seconds:

```
host% time vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 10.0.0.2
  User vagrant
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

1.614u 0.487s 0:12.27 17.0%     0+0k 0+24io 0pf+0w
host%
```

This is presumably what is causing `vagrant ssh` to also take 12 seconds (by comparison, `ssh -p2222 vagrant@localhost` does not use `vagrant ssh-config`, and takes only 1 second).

My `Vagrantfile` is:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box              = "bento/ubuntu-18.10"
  config.vm.box_version      = "201906.18.0"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.hostname         = "demo"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.2"
  # enables, for example, 'ssh vagrant@10.0.0.2'

  # None of these actually work. Boo.
  #config.ssh.host = "10.0.0.2"
  #config.ssh.port = 22
  #config.ssh.username   = 'root'
  #config.ssh.password   = 'vagrant'
  #config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name   = config.vm.hostname
    vb.memory = "2048"
    vb.cpus   = "2"
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end

  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "Hello, World!"
  SHELL

end
```

If I run `vagrant ssh-config --debug`, it prints the following before waiting about 11 seconds:

```
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_load #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x0000000001e95f60>
DEBUG checkpoint_client: starting plugin check
 INFO cli: CLI: [] "ssh-config" []
DEBUG cli: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandSSHConfig::Command []
DEBUG checkpoint_client: waiting for checkpoint to complete...
```

Then it prints up to this point:

```
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "--version"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
```

and hangs for 0.5 seconds, and then prints some other stuff and the above lines again, and hangs for another 0.5 seconds, before finishing.

I would expect `vagrant ssh-config` to be just querying Vagrant's data structure, and I would expect this to be efficiently implemented so that it can complete in a few milliseconds at most. Instead, it is doing something apparently quite involved.

I noticed that other commands like `vagrant destroy --debug` have similar behavior. I.e., they have a long pause after `waiting for checkpoint` and shorter pauses after `Selecting on IO`.

Were Vagrant commands such as `vagrant ssh-config` and `vagrant destroy` designed to be this slow? Any thoughts on how to make vagrant commands run faster? Can the slow parts be bypassed?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a widely reported issue and to my knowledge there is no way to bypass certain portions. If the speeds are really bothering you I would look at removing all of Vagrant including the `~/.vagrant.d` directory, restart your computer, and re-install the latest version of Vagrant from the official [Vagrant installers](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/). To see if that speeds things up. It may also be useful to run `vagrant global-status` to see if running a few boxes are hindering your speeds.

Comment: Probably not widely reported because it is easy to bypass. I bypassed "vagrant ssh" by having the provision script dump a local script that has the machine address and ssh key hard-coded into it. Runs 20X faster now.